# Is there a way to duplicate parameters in the graphql schema?

Tags: graphql, serverless, apollo-server

I actually have a question while applying graphql.

When using graphql, parameters to shcema are often the same or almost similar.

Is there a way to duplicate a parameter in a schema?

ex)

createArticle (title: String!, contents: String!, userId: String!): Article

updateArticle (articleNo: Int, title: String!, contents: String!, userId: String!): Int

Comment: why don't you use an object in your query variables, then reference that object in the input?

Comment: @DanStarns Thank you for your reply
When referencing the object, we did not use it because we had to pass the data from the front-end to the object.